# How to access the current submitted Google Forms survey?

Tags: google-forms

I want to embed a Google Forms survey on my website and return a message regarding to the input.

The process should look like this: User fills in a survey, clicks on 'submit' and gets directly an answer based on the input before. I have seen that I can access to the Google Forms fields with the `FormApp` class of the GSuite, but is there an equivalent for the responses? 
Since the form is for many users online how can I guarantee that the data I am using for the algorithm are the data of this specific user?
My idea was that I just use the last response but it also may happen that another user submits his survey in the same time and the data are reversed. Or do I have a mistake in my thinking?